# Angular 2 : Routing with different types of slugs

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my component I have list of menu items. One consist of post other of pages.

menu.component.ts

```
selectedPost(postslug){
  console.log('post slg ', postslug);
    this._router.navigate([postslug]);
}

selectedPage(pageslug){
  console.log('page slg ', pageslug);
    this._router.navigate([pageslug]);
}
```

app.routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PostListComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }

  ,
  {
       path: ':postslug',  // This is for the posts 
      component: PostSingleComponent,
  }
    ,
  {
     path: ':pageslug',
     component: PageSingleComponent  // This is for the pages 
  }


];
```

As I understood that because of custom slug that I pass it should pick up and load the correct component. But it load the first one that has  ': + something'.

Is there a way around this ?

If there isn't is there a way to push via the function a custom category, and in the routing to redirect to the category?

For example in the function:

```
  selectedPost(catName, postslug){
      console.log('post slg ', postslug);
        this._router.navigate([catName, postslug]);
    }
```

And in the routing I would have:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PostListComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }

  ,
  {
       path: 'catName/:postslug',  // This is for the posts 
      component: PostSingleComponent,
  }
    ,
  {
     path: ':pageslug',
     component: PageSingleComponent  // This is for the pages 
  }


];
```

Comment: Put yourself in the shoes of the router. You're being asked to navigate to /1234. How can you possibly know if 1234 is a post or a page? How about using /posts/1234, and /pages/1234?

Comment: tha'ts what i tried in my other example but didn't work also. As I don't know how to pass custom category also.

Comment: If the value of the catName variable is either 'posts' or 'pages', then you need a route for the path 'posts/:postslug`, and another one for 'pages/:pageslug'.

Answer (score 2):

try below,

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PostListComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }

  ,
  {
       path: 'posts/:postslug',  // This is for the posts 
      component: PostSingleComponent,
  }
    ,
  {
     path: 'pages/:pageslug',
     component: PageSingleComponent  // This is for the pages 
  }
];
```

and on click,

```
selectedPost(postslug){
  console.log('post slg ', postslug);
    this._router.navigate(['posts',postslug]);
}

selectedPage(pageslug){
  console.log('page slg ', pageslug);
    this._router.navigate(['pages',pageslug]);
}
```

Check documentation on [How Routing works here.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#basics-config), it explains in detail about Routing and Navigation.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you Madhu, but If I understood angular doc I wouldn't be asking on stack-overflow. I only started to understand there documentation after months of coding in angular.  I will try this out in couple of hours and give u feedback. Thank you again.

Comment: Any doc can be sometimes be overwhelming, I would suggest to give docs another try and time, angular team and community has done tremendous job in creating those for us, Cheers!!